# What is best way to use angularjs pagination?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

**I am brand new to AngularJS** and when I was searching about the best way to do the pagination using angularjs, I saw two kinds of libraries to achieve this.

using
 **1. ngTable**
      *or*
 **2. dir-paginate**

I want to know what is the best approach to add pagination from above two.

Also, If above two are not the way to do it, what is best way to add pagination using angularjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want table  with pagination and sorting etc. you can go with `ngTable`. This is the directive for overall table.

if you want only add `pagination`, then go with `dir-pagination` . this directive is only for pagination.

So,

- `ngTable` - directive for table
- `dir-pagination` - directive for pagination.